# Possibility to only retreive owners data with prisma2 and nexus

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

When posting a query i want to retreive only the data that is assigned to the current user (id).

I retreive and set the `userId` with a middleware function that contains;

```
const userId = tokenPayload['claims']['uid'];
ctx.userId = userId;
```

Base on the `userId` i need to filter the data from models like this;

```
model Address {
  id                   String      @id @default(uuid())
  name                 string
  ...
  user                 User
}
```

so i want to return the equivalent to `Addresses.filter(address => address.user.id === ctx.userId)`

(the `Addresses` where the `user.id` is equal to the one set in the middleware)

for example something like this (this is made-up code so it doenst work)

```
plugins: [nexusPrismaPlugin(
    {
      computedInputs: {
      ...
      },
      computedFilters: {
        addresses: ({ ctx }) => ({ where: { user: { id: ctx.userId } } }),
        relations: ({ ctx }) => ({ where: { user: { id: ctx.userId } } }),
        ...
      }
    }
  )],
```

Where the `computedFilters` filters the incoming query to match the requirements that are set in the `where` statement.
So with this set it should only return the `adresses` and / or `relations` where `user.id === ctx.userId`.

I hope it is clear what i want to achieve, it doensn't have to be like this, the only thing that needs to be the same is the response in the most performant way.

I hope someone can help, i'm struggeling with the current issue for the last couple of weeks..

Comment: Can you not use a filter on a batchRead? See: https://github.com/prisma-labs/nexus-prisma#batch-filtering and https://github.com/prisma-labs/nexus-prisma#filtering

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? @RMCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by editing the generated resolvers;

by replacing

```
t.crud.addresses({filtering: true, ordering: true});
```

with

```
t.list.field('addresses', {
      type: 'Address',
      resolve: (_parent, _args, ctx) => {
        return ctx.prisma.address.findMany({
          where: {
            user: {
              id: ctx.userId
            }
          }
        })
      }
    });
```